# Bootstrap having a little issue with nesting

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, nested, grid

I'm having some issues with Bootstrap nesting.

I'm trying to do an image grid like this:
[image]
my current code:

```
<div class="row"> 

<div class="col-md-4"><div style="background-color: red;">1</div></div>
<div class="col-md-4">                            
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-2"><div style="background-color:green;">2</div></div>
<div class="col-md-2"><div style="background-color:blue;">3</div></div>        
</div>     

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4"><div style="background-color: grey;">5</div></div>
</div>    
</div>

<div class="col-md-3"><div style="background-color: purple;">4</div></div>  

</div>
```

but what I am currently getting is:

[image]
Does anyone have any ideas of what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nesting in your case seems wrong. You should treat the 30% of the space as completely a new row. It should be `col-md-6` for both 2 and 3. I guess you need to use `container-fluid` for this kind of layout and try it out this way:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div style="background-color: red;">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div style="background-color:green;">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div style="background-color:blue;">3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div style="background-color: grey;">5</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
      <div style="background-color: purple;">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **Note:** I have changed all the classes to `xs-*` to facilitate the preview as well. You can change it to `md-*` in your application.

Also, for getting a `masonry` style output, you might need to add some extra classes for telling that it should take two element height, etc.

```css
.row {margin-bottom: 25px;}
.height-2x {line-height: 1.75;}
.height-2x > div {padding-bottom: 40px;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 height-2x">
      <div style="background-color: red;">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div style="background-color:green;">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <div style="background-color:blue;">3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div style="background-color: grey;">5</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 height-2x">
      <div style="background-color: purple;">4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help u.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
}

.col-xs-6 {
  height: 100px;
}

.row {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.col-xs-4 {
  height: 180px;
}

.div1,
.div4 {
  background: green;
}

.div2 > div,
.div3 > div,
.div5 > div {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
}

.div5 > div {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-4 div1">1</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 div2">
        <div>2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 div3">
        <div>3</div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 div5">
        <div>5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-4 div4">4</div>
</div>
```

[image]